# Problem with def and while True function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

What's wrong with this that ain't working. I have to ask user for command and if command from setAction() is = 'temp' i have to just do delete() but that's not working.

```
import glob
import os

def setAction(action):
    action = input('Mt Manager> ')

def delete():
    pattern = r"C:/Users/kpola/AppData/Local/Temp/**/*"

    for item in glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True):
        # delete file
        print("Deleting:", item)
        os.remove(item) 
 
while True:

    if setAction('temp'):
        delete()
        print('Hello world')
    else:
        quit()
```

Comment: Among other things that are wrong in this code, your `setAction()` does not return anything (which means it returns `None` in python). So when you do `if setAction()`, it evaluates to false and you always hit the `else`. I believe you are trying to do `return action == input(...`

Answer (score 0):

In the function `setAction` you are only assinging `action` to `temp` over and over again. And since `setAction` has no return statement it will always return `None`

```py
def setAction(action):
    return input('Mt Manager> ') == action
```

This snipped should return if your input is equal to "temp"